# WebRequest fails when executed in Asp.net server side but passes when executed from Windows application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, httpwebrequest

**IIS 8 & Windows 8**

I have below sample code which I am trying to check whether a url exists, when I ran from console app it works fine, response is obtained, but when executed from server side ASP.net page it throws socket exception.

Sample code:

```
try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("HTTPS://test");
                WebRequest http = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            }
            catch (UriFormatException sds)
            {
            }
            catch (IOException sdsd)
            {
            }
```

Error:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Any suggestions in this regard would helpful.

Comment: possibly the website has blocked the server(asp running pc) IP?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, my guess would be that the asp.net application is running under an account which does not have enough privs to access a network resource. You can try changing the account under which the asp.net application runs or impersonate a user with network access rights.